# Callbacks in REST web service

Tags: c#, .net, rest, callback

I am working on C#/.Net4.5/VS2017CE, and am developing REST service APIs. Forgive me if this may be a rather broad question; however, I am new to developing REST APIs.

I need to have some way to communicate changes at the server to all interested clients, and to this end, I am looking for some kind of callback mechanism. I am not too keen on polling as it may be costly in my case owing to the potentially large number of client instances.

Needless to add, the server is agnostic of the client platform.

Comment: SignalR.NET....

Comment: Will SignalR work regardless of the client platform?

Comment: Please read https://www.asp.net/signalr, there you will find all required information. Alternative you can also use websocket server, where you clients can subscript to a specific event, and you server can publish events to it.

Answer (score 1):

RestService work like `ask` and `answer`. And if you have an answer and want to say without asking you need to use like  open communication.This is means all the client can already waiting your answer. There are some way to do this you can search about signalR , rabbitmq , service bus